# Problema al pasar de varchar a decimal en PHP MyAdmin (importando ods)

Tags: phpmyadmin, formato

he importado a PHP MyAdmin una tabla en formato "ods" y estoy tratanto de cambiar el formato de un dato que se importa como varchar y lo quiero tener como precio, es decir, en formato decimal.

El problema es que al cambiar el formato de varchar a decimal en PHP MyAdmin, elimina todos los decimales, dejando solo la parte entera.

He probado cambiando el separador de decimales que trae Excel por defecto, de punto a coma, también he probado cambiando el formato de las celdas a moneda, a número quitando el separador de miles o personalizada, y después importando el archivo ods nuevamente a PHP MyAdmin, pero ninguna de estas alternativas ha funcionado ya que en todos los casos al cambiar el formato de varchar a decimal en PHP MyAdmin elimina la parte decimal y deja solo la cifra con la parte entera.

Si alguien sabe alguna otra alternativa que se me esté escapando o cómo solucionarlo le estaré muy agradecido.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El formato de la columna donde se guardan esos datos debe ser `DECIMAL` o `FLOAT`.

Cambia la definición de esa columna a ese tipo de datos y luego intenta hacer la importación.

De otro modo, deberás crear otra columna con dicho tipo de datos para poder hacer la conversión con una consulta similar:

```sql
UPDATE tu_tabla SET columna_decimal = columna_varchar;
```

Comment: El asunto es que la tabla no existe, es decir, para crearla he importado un archivo ods.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo de la form aque indicas? Es decir, ¿debería crear las cabeceras a mano y subir despues el archivo ods pero sin incluir las cabeceras de dicho archivo, subiendo solo los datos de cada columna?

Comment: Si al crear las cabeceras a mano, el programa te permite especificar sus tipos de datos, puedes hacerlo de esa manera.